# Epoch time using Salesforce apex code

Tags: javascript, jquery, salesforce, apex-code

How to get the epoch time using apex code? There are examples using programming languages but not with apex code. Please help.

Microsoft .NET C#   epoch = (DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().Ticks - 621355968000000000) / 10000000;

Java    long epoch = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;

Comment: **Fixed:**      DateTime current = System.now();
            Long timeInMili = current.getTime()/1000;
            String s_time=String.valueOf(integer.valueof(timeInMili));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you check the [documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm)?

```
datetime dt = datetime.now();
system.debug(dt);
system.debug(dt.getTime());
```

output:

```
|USER_DEBUG|[2]|DEBUG|2013-02-25 10:53:48
|USER_DEBUG|[3]|DEBUG|1361789628679
```

Comment: Code given in the comments(**Fixed**) works for me. Thanks anyway

Comment: The last 3 number are not required for epoch hence i divide it by 1000 to make correct. Thanks a lot for response.